# How to add multiple values in a single row of a column using php into mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I am HR and new for Developing. I started doing program for HR management using PHP and Mysql. I want to add the names of atleast 5 employees in a single row of a column. I use bootstrap to get multiple values in a single field. But when I try to insert the values, only the last value is inserted.

```
<td>Distribute</td><td><input type="text" class="form-control"  name="distribute[]"></td>
```

HTML Code:

```
<tr><td>Distribute</td><td><input type="text" class="form-control"  name="distribute[]"></td></tr>
```

PHP to insert into mysql

```
$civil_id= $_POST['civil_id'];

    $name= $_POST['name']; 
    $card_type = $_POST['card_type']; 
    $count = $_POST['count']; 
    $amt=$card_type * $count;
    $avail_bal=$_POST['balance']- $amt; 
    $issue_year= $_POST['issue_year']; 
    $issue_month= $_POST['issue_month']; 
    $issue_date= $_POST['issue_date']; 
    $distribute= $_POST['distribute'];

$sql ="insert into group_phone
(civil_id,
name,
card_type,
count,
amt,
avail_bal,issue_year,issue_month,issue_date,distribute)values('$civil_id',
'$name',
'$card_type',
'$count',
'$amt',
'$avail_bal','$issue_year','$issue_month','$issue_date','$distribute')";
```

HTML

```js
<script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".select2_single").select2({
          placeholder: "Select Vehicle Plate Number",
          allowClear: true
        });
        $(".select2_group").select2({});
        $(".select2_multiple").select2({
          maximumSelectionLength: 10,
          placeholder: "With Max Selection limit 10",
          allowClear: true
        });
      });
    </script>
```

```html
<form class="form-horizontal form-label-left" action="new_rechargecard.php" method="POST" ">
                    <table id="datatable" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                      


                      <tbody>
       
        <tr>
           <td width='100'>Employee Name: </td><td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="0" name="name" value="<?php echo "$name";?>" ></td> 
    
</tr>
                       
                      
        
        
                          
    <tr>
 
 <td>Available Balance</td><td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="0" name="balance" value=<?php echo $balance;?> > </td></tr> 
     <tr><td>Civil id</td><td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Civil ID Required" name="civil_id" value=<?php echo $pass_name;?> > </td></tr>
  <!--<tr><td>Name</td><td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>" > </td></tr>-->
  
   
  <tr><td width='250'>Card Type (1 KD or 2.5 KD or 5 KD)</td><td><input type="text" class="form-control"   name="card_type"></td></tr>
  <tr><td width='200'>Card Count</td><td><input type="text" class="form-control"  name="count"></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Issue Year</td><td><input type="text" class="form-control"  name="issue_year" value="<?php echo date('Y'); ?>"></td></tr>
   <tr><td>For the Month of</td><td><input type="text" class="form-control"  name="issue_month" value="<?php echo date('M'); ?>"></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Issue date</td><td><input type="text" class="form-control"  name="issue_date"></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Distribute</td><td><select name="distribute" class="select2_multiple form-control" tabindex="-1"  multiple="multiple">
  <option></option>
     <option>Richard Marcus</option>     
     <option>Rowlant S Peter</option> 
     <option>David.K.Rumpell</option> 
     <option>John Mathew</option>  
     </select>
  </td></tr>
  
 
   
     <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" class="btn btn-round btn-danger" value="Update" name="submit"></td></tr>
  </tbody>
     </table>
  </form>
```

Comment: Please refer this link https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/

Comment: show complete code

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: 'multiple values in a single field' :-(

Answer (score 1):

### Change your code like this

```
<?php

/* First create mysql connection */

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "userlist";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

/* End */

    $civil_id= $_POST['civil_id'];

    $name= $_POST['name']; 
    $card_type = $_POST['card_type']; 
    $count = $_POST['count']; 
    $amt=$card_type * $count;
    $avail_bal=$_POST['balance']- $amt; 
    $issue_year= $_POST['issue_year']; 
    $issue_month= $_POST['issue_month']; 
    $issue_date= $_POST['issue_date']; 
    $distribute= $_POST['distribute'];

$sql ="insert into group_phone
(civil_id,
name,
card_type,
count,
amt,
avail_bal,issue_year,issue_month,issue_date,distribute)values('".$civil_id."',
'".$name."',
'".$card_type."',
'".$count."',
'".$amt."',
'".$avail_bal."','".$issue_year."','".$issue_month."','".$issue_date."','".$distribute."')";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

> MySQL table structure

### -- Table structure for table `userlist`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `userlist` (
  `civil_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `card_type` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `count` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `amt` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `avail_bal` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `issue_year` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `issue_month` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `issue_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `distribute` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`civil_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

> Working Query (MySQL)

```
INSERT INTO `userlist` (`civil_id`, `name`, `card_type`, `count`, `amt`, `avail_bal`, `issue_year`, `issue_month`, `issue_date`, `distribute`) VALUES
(1, 'aman,suresh,mohan', 'POST', 10, 500, 50, 2016, 'March', '2017-02-01 06:46:16', 'Airtel,Idea,Vodafone');
```

Comment: Do try and link to the official documentation whenever possible. w3schools has created a lot of problems here by recommending bad practices.

Comment: you may try my code ..  i think this may help you to resolve your query ...

Comment: Switching from interpolated code of the form `,'$x',` to concatenated code like `,'" . $x . "',` doesn't change anything substantial, both evaluate the same way. To be correct this code should employ [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php).

Comment: Yes Aman Kumar. No changes. I agree with tadman. I wanna add 4 or 5 names in the distribute column for the particular employee. Ex- Employee X, Distribute=a,b,c,d,e

Comment: Or you can try to insert all the comma separate value into database in json format but "Distribute" datatype must be varchar

Comment: I just gave the varchar length even 700 to test but only single name is inserted

Comment: @Lina you need to show more code. Show your form, presumably this is where you are adding your names?

Comment: My database table name is " userlist " and i show structure and query in above code ..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have solved this, but you just need to do an arrayed `distribute` name in the form then use a built-in function to turn the array to string, some popular functions are `serialize()` or `json_encode()`. I prefer the latter because JavaScript can use it, but in terms of *best practice*, it is generally frowned upon to store an array into a database like this. I have found it is useful for one-time instances where targeted searching is not required now or in the future. I would use it very sparingly. In this instance you may want to create a separate table that stores the names separately and join them when you go to select them later.

Also, for my example, I have used PDO instead of `mysqli_` but the principles are the same. Look into [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). Finally, I would look at creating some useful classes that will help clean up the script. The ones I have below are some basic examples.

**/classes/User.php**

```
# I would think about containing your script in a class, this is just
# a bare-bones example
class   User
    {
        public  function __construct(PDO $db)
            {
                $this->db   =   $db;
            }

        protected   function getAmount($a, $b)
            {
                return $a*$b;
            }

        protected   function getBalance($a,$b)
            {
                return $a-$b;
            }

        public  function addUser($array)
            {
                $bind   =   array(
                    $_POST['civil_id'],
                    $_POST['name'],
                    $_POST['card_type'],
                    $_POST['count'],
                    $amt = $this->getAmount($_POST['card_type'],$_POST['count']),
                    $this->getBalance($_POST['balance'],$amt),
                    $_POST['issue_year'],
                    $_POST['issue_month'],
                    $_POST['issue_date'],
                    json_encode($_POST['distribute'])
                );

                $sql ="INSERT INTO group_phone 
                    (civil_id,name,card_type,count,amt,avail_bal,issue_year,issue_month,issue_date,distribute)
                values
                    (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

                $query  =   $this->db->prepare($sql);
                $query->execute($bind);
            }
    }
```

**/classes/Database.php**

```
# This would need to be filled out and made to work with yours
# This is demonstration purposes only
class Database
    {
        private static  $con;

        public  function connect()
            {
                if(self::$con instanceof PDO)
                    return self::$con;

                self::$con  =   new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=databasename;","username","password");

                return self::$con;
            }
    }
```

**/new_rechargecard.php**

```
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('ROOT_DIR', __DIR__);
define('CLASSES', ROOT_DIR.DS.'classes');
# Create a class autoloader
spl_autoload_register(function($class){
    $inc = CLASSES.DS.trim(str_replace('\\',DS,$class),DS).'.php';
    if(file_exists($inc))
        include_once($inc);
});
# Create db
$con    =   (new Database())->connect();
# Check for update
if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'update_user') {
    # Create user instance
    $User   =   new User($con);
    # Add into database
    $User->addUser($_POST);
}
?>
```

**Form HTML:**

```
<form class="form-horizontal form-label-left" action="new_rechargecard.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="update_user" />
    <table id="datatable" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td width='100'>Employee Name: </td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="0" name="name" value="<?php echo $name ?>" ></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Available Balance</td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="0" name="balance" value=<?php echo $balance ?> ></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Civil id</td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Civil ID Required" name="civil_id" value=<?php echo $pass_name;?> ></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width='250'>Card Type (1 KD or 2.5 KD or 5 KD)</td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control"   name="card_type"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width='200'>Card Count</td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control"  name="count"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Issue Year</td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control"  name="issue_year" value="<?php echo date('Y'); ?>"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>For the Month of</td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control"  name="issue_month" value="<?php echo date('M'); ?>"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Issue date</td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control"  name="issue_date"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Distribute</td>
                <td><select name="distribute[]" class="select2_multiple form-control" tabindex="-1"  multiple="multiple">
                        <option></option>
                        <option>Richard Marcus</option>
                        <option>Rowlant S Peter</option>
                        <option>David.K.Rumpell</option>
                        <option>John Mathew</option>
                    </select></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="submit" class="btn btn-round btn-danger" value="Update"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```